# Python threading help Needed

Tags: python, multithreading

I am snowblind from looking at examples that don't exactly fit my case ... or maybe they do. So if there are great examples out there for this, I have not been able to interpret them with about 3 weeks of Python experience

I have a script that queries a database, gathers a list of downloadable movies, then downloads them to your chosen directory, one by one. And I would like to make it download 4 or 5 at once, as it takes an age to do it.

Here is a simplified version what I have attempted to do, myapp is my database application. However it appears to just run sequential, even though it says it's starting both threads

listOfIDs are the ids of some containers that may or may not have movies, then versionS returns the movie file names.

```
import threading
import myapp_api

listOfIDs = (14809, 14808, 14807, 14806, 14805, 14804, 14803)
for ID in listOfIDs:
    versionS = myapp.find_one('Version', [['id', 'is', ID]], ['uploaded_movie'])

ipath = ('/Users/me/Desktop/scripts/downloads/')

exitFlag = 0

class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        for ID in listOfIDs:
            print "\nID= " + str(ID) + "\n"
            downLoad(ID)
        print "Exiting " + self.name

def downLoad(ID):
    versionS = myapp.find_one('Version', [['id', 'is', ID]], ['uploaded_movie'])
    path = ipath + (str(versionS).split("'")[5])
    result = myapp.download_attachment(attachment=versionS['uploaded_movie'], file_path=path)
    print "Thread Name = " + threadName


# Create new threads
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", 1)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", 2)


# Start new Threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Ok, so I altered the code to take on the suggestion by `ShadowRanger` and it is still just downloading one at a time, have I stuffed this up somewhere? ... code looks like this now.

```
import threading
import myapp_api
from collections import deque

listOfIDs = (14809, 14808, 14807, 14806, 14805, 14804, 14803)
for ID in listOfIDs:
    versionS = myapp.find_one('Version', [['id', 'is', ID]], ['uploaded_movie'])

ipath = ('/Users/me/Desktop/scripts/downloads/')

def downLoad(ID):
    path = ipath + (str(versionS).split("'")[5])
    result = myapp.download_attachment(attachment=versionS['uploaded_movie'], file_path=path)

with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(4)) as pool:
    deque(pool.imap_unordered(downLoad, listOfIDs), maxlen=0)
```

And finally, All the advice by `ShadowRanger` was spot on, the error was in something I had done incorrectly (I think I was iterating over the listOfIDs early, and only passing the last one out to the function) ... here is the final working version.

```
   import threading
    import myapp_api
    from collections import deque

listOfIDs = (14809, 14808, 14807, 14806, 14805, 14804, 14803)

ipath = ('/Users/me/Desktop/scripts/downloads/')

def downLoad(ID):
    versionS = myapp.find_one('Version', [['id', 'is', ID]], ['uploaded_movie'])
    path = ipath + (str(versionS).split("'")[5])
    result = myapp.download_attachment(attachment=versionS['uploaded_movie'], file_path=path)


with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(4)) as pool:
    deque(pool.imap_unordered(downLoad, listOfIDs), maxlen=0)
```

Comment: If the code in question is delegating to modules that are implemented in Python, the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) is going to cause issues with threading. Normally, I/O bound stuff like DB access will release the GIL while blocking waiting for results, but I don't know what libraries you're using. For that matter, if the libraries lock internally, that would render the threading useless.

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell if I am getting GIL due to these other libraries locking internally

Comment: GIL and library internal locking are completely separate. Changing `import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing` back to `import multiprocessing` (so you run a separate processes, rather than threads) will largely remove the GIL (and for that matter, probably avoid library locks), at the expense of adding overhead for interprocess communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the threads are splitting work. Looks like they both download the same set of things.

If the goal is to download a bunch of files based on known IDs, `multiprocessing` has a `.dummy` module that can act like `multiprocessing` but implemented using threads, which gets you an easy thread pool:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as multiprocessing
from contextlib import closing

with closing(multiprocessing.Pool(4)) as pool: # Pick your favorite number of workers
    pool.map(downLoad, listOfIDs)
```

Comment: `pool.map` returns a list of the values returned by the `map`-ed function, `downLoad` in this case; since it has no `return` statement, it creates (and then promptly discards) a list of `None`s. Not a big deal in most cases, but if your list is huge, you can avoid the unnecessary waste by adding an import for `from collections import deque` and changing the `pool.map` line to `deque(pool.imap_unordered(downLoad, listOfIDs), maxlen=0)` which avoids storing the return values unnecessarily (`deque` with `maxlen=0` is the most efficient way to run an iterator to exhaustion, discarding results).

Comment: I have now rolled this sample into my "actual" script, line for line, and it crashes python every time. ... I have checked that what gets fed in to this in the main script is the same as what I am hard coding into the test, and that all checks out. I am doing this on a Mac, and the crash report that comes up mentions `crashed on child side of fork pre-exec` ... so I was wondering where I may dig deeper... throwing a `dig()` clearly shows a lot more vars floating around in the main script, but I am not sure which of them, if any, might be adversely affecting this.

Comment: This look like your problem? http://blog.yimingliu.com/2015/07/22/python-multiprocessing-code-crashes-on-os-x-under-ipython/ Or this? https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2902 It looks like the Mac builds of Python have had some repeated issues with this.

Comment: Looks like it, yes, I just ran the problem script on Linux, and no problems, it runs the the proverbial scalded feline ... with no errors reported. I will try to fix it up, but knowing what the actual error is, is great.